# Simple onclick event worked only once

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Help please) Why this construction does not work? The increment happens only once.

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

function moveDown(object) {
    object.style.top += 32;
}

button.onclick = function() {
    moveDown(player);
}
```

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SrQUh/1/

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

function moveDown(object) {
  object.style.top = parseInt(object.style.top || 0) + 32 + 'px';
}

button.onclick = function() {
    moveDown(player);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`object.style.top = parseInt(object.style.top, 10) + 32;`

instead of

`object.style.top+=32;`

(And make sure player's `position` is set to `absolute` or `relative`)

Comment: not worked. ` function moveDown(object) {
 object.style.top = parseInt(object.style.top , 10) + 32;
 console.log(parseInt(object.style.top , 10));
} `

Comment: change it to object.style.top = parseInt(object.style.top || 0, 10) + 32;