# JavaScript onclick event works only once

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple HTML page that contains a paragraph with some classes and a button with a random predefined name that will be chosen from an array, and another paragraph to show the result.

I made a function that will check if the button's name exists as a class in the first paragraph if so it will write in the last paragraph "It exists.". If not it will show "No it doesn't.".

The function will be triggered when I click the button. The problem that it works only once. Here is the code

```js
var mainParagraph = document.getElementById("test-paragraph"),
  buttonCheck = document.getElementById("class-checker"),
  resultContainer = document.getElementById("result-container");
// An array of possible names of the button
var buttonName = ["test", "two", "random", "fly", "false", "checked", "wrong", "last", "process", "end"],
  x = Math.random() * 10,
  z = Math.floor(x);
//change the button's name each time the button is clicked. "not working."
function butonClicked() {
  'use strict';
  buttonCheck.textContent = buttonName[z];
}
// function to check if button's name is the same as a class in the first paragraph
function checkTheClass() {
  'use strict';
  if(mainParagraph.classList.contains(buttonName[z])) {
    resultContainer.textContent = "yes the class exists. It's : " + '"' + buttonName[z] + '"';
  } else {
    resultContainer.textContent = "No the class doesn't exists.";
  }
}
// Trigger the function when the button is clicked
buttonCheck.onclick = function() {
  'use strict';
  butonClicked();
  checkTheClass();
};
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p id="test-paragraph" class="test random checked work done process"> This is a random text to be use for the test
    <br/> these are the classes: test, random, checked, work, done, process. </p>
  <button id="class-checker">click!</button>
  <p id="result-container">Here is the result</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I already checked these answers, but I still can't solve the problem:

[Simple onclick event worked only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241535/simple-onclick-event-worked-only-once).
[onclick event works only once in arctext script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699306/onclick-event-works-only-once-in-arctext-script).
Here is the code in Codepen:  http://s.codepen.io/Noureddine/debug/JbbBQX.

Ps: I don't know JQquery

Comment: Well you only execute the random part once. If you want it to execute again, you need to move that logic inside.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand. Can you explain more or supply me with a link where I can read more because I  am not advanced in JavaScript. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that your event is getting fired only once but the variable `z` is not updated each time so it keeps trying to grab the same index from your array.

```
buttonCheck.onclick = function () {
    'use strict';
    z = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10);
    butonClicked();
    checkTheClass();

};
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. I realized that just adding a console.log(buttonName[z]);  in the buttonCheck function will make it clear that z remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of button.onclick, you can use addEventListener for binding click event and another thing...Z and x variables will have random values only once if you want them to change may be include it in the click handler

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var mainParagraph = document.getElementById("test-paragraph"),
    buttonCheck = document.getElementById("class-checker"),
    resultContainer = document.getElementById("result-container");

  // An array of possible names of the button

  var buttonName = ["test", "two", "random", "fly", "false", "checked", "wrong", "last", "process", "end"];

  var x;
  var z;
  //change the button's name each time the button is clicked. "not working."

  function butonClicked() {
    'use strict';
    x = Math.random() * 10;
    z = Math.floor(x);
    buttonCheck.textContent = buttonName[z];

  }

  // function to check if button's name is the same as a class in the first paragraph

  function checkTheClass() {
    'use strict';
    if (mainParagraph.classList.contains(buttonName[z])) {

      resultContainer.textContent = "yes the class exists. It's : " + '"' + buttonName[z] + '"';
    } else {

      resultContainer.textContent = "No the class doesn't exists.";

    }
  }


  buttonCheck.addEventListener('click', function() {
    butonClicked()
    checkTheClass()
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="test-paragraph" class="test random checked work done process">
    This is a random text to be use for the test
    <br/>these are the classes: test, random, checked, work, done, process.
  </p>

  <button id="class-checker">click!</button>

  <p id="result-container">Here is the result</p>

</body>
```

Hope it helps